What were the norms of inheritance in Jewish culture? When and why would there be exceptions?
I was reading a question on the hermeneutical site about Jacob taking Esau’s blessing and there was a question raised in the comments of “Was Esau’s inheritance even something to be negotiated?” Which I thought was an excellent question but which might be better answered here.
So what were the norms of inheritance in Jewish culture and for what reasons might exceptions be made?

I recommend first consulting chatgpt for all such basic questions, it's the best source for firsthand search

@Michael16 One of the signs of the end of the world is the subjugation of humanity to a non-human influence (not of the Holy Spirit) which influence insinuates itself into the sphere of genuine religion as if it were divine.

Nigel, that is only the view of 21st century American end times theology.

Okay. Still I did search the stack exchange and it didn’t have much about the norms and exceptions of inheritance, so I thought it might be some interesting information to have here on the site, but I’ll go do some research on my own and see what I find. :) Thanks!
